# How to align const indent in ESLint?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants, eslint

I'm using [ESLint](http://eslint.org/) to make my JavaScript code style consistent. My favorite indentation level is 4 and I want my declarations style to be this:

```
function () {
    let a = 1,
        bbb = 2;

    const cc = 3,
          ddd = 4;
}
```

There is a problem though, since [indent](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent) rule per each structure takes a number, which is multiplication of base indentation. If I set my basic indentation to 4, I don't seem to be able to align consts.

If I set the rule to:

```
"indent": ["error", 4, {"VariableDeclarator": {"const": 1}}],
```

The correct align will be 4 spaces:

```
const cc = 3,
    ddd = 4;
```

And if I set the rule to 2:

```
"indent": ["error", 4, {"VariableDeclarator": {"const": 2}}],
```

It's going to expect 8 spaces:

```
const cc = 3,
        ddd = 4;
```

It doesn't accept floating numbers. How can I align var, let and const the way I want using ESLint?

Comment: Indent with 4 spaces and forget about it.

Comment: Have a look at http://eslint.org/docs/rules/key-spacing#align-and-multiline

Comment: @mfirry I think this rule cannot be applied for separate variables and consts, but only for properties inside objects.

Comment: @trincot That's very ambitious approach.

Comment: I think the answer is "you can't". I think aligning with the previous line isn't something you usually see in JS code. Like if you had a function with arguments that were on multiple lines, you don't indent the args to match the previous line, either.

Comment: @loganfsmyth After a while of research I agree that it's probably impossible. What I don't agree with though, is that it's rare in JS. Aligning `var` this way is very, very common. It's just a coinsidence that `var` plus space is 4 characters long. Same goes for `let`. Parameter list is another story, because it's not a block per se.

Comment: Yeah it's one of those cases where 100% nailing down any given style isn't always possible. I've working on codebase with 2-space indent, so aligning `var` and `let` don't work on those, and then some codebases use http://eslint.org/docs/rules/one-var anyway because many people find the multi-declarations in general hard to read, indentation-aside. Style is hard. I'm slowly coming around to understanding why people like the new formatter https://github.com/prettier/prettier since then you just don't have to think about it all.

Comment: Solution: Use a single variable, const, let statement per binding :)

Answer (score 4):

According https://eslint.org/docs/rules/indent you can use:

`indent: ["error", 2, { "VariableDeclarator": { "var": 2, "let": 2, "const": 3 } }`

Also you can avoid this problem using next rules:
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/one-var
https://eslint.org/docs/rules/one-var-declaration-per-line

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's worth to try:

```
function () {
    let a = 1,
        bbb = 2;

    const 
        cc = 3,
        ddd = 4;
}
```